# Exact Target subscriber activation

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a subscriber in Exact Target who was not active for the last 6 months with a couple of emails sent out to him were bounced. I need to reactivate the user as he is greyed out at present and cannot receive any email communications.

Answer (score 2):

If the Subscriber is 'greyed' out, this would indicate that they have a Held (Undeliverable) status.

To reactivate the Subscriber, create a CSV file with the subscriber details, including a column for Subscriber Key and Status and set the status to 'Active'.

Click on the Import button on the All Subscribers page and ensure that Update Option is set to 'Update existing subscribers'.